# Stuck on gnu grub command shell while reinstalling ubuntu

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, live-usb, gnu

So I was planning to reinstall ubuntu ,for that I create a bootable pen drive with ubuntu 22.04 on it ,so when I insert into my pc ,the ubuntu 22.04 gets installed ,but when I remove the usb drive ,the ubuntu is gone ,and when I power up ,I am stuck on gnu grub command shell.Now when I insert usb drive into the pc ,then only the boot menu came ,otherwise it is stuck on gnusrub shell ,how to resolve this issue ,can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to boot the old install of grub which now is not correct. Did you install in same boot mode UEFI or BIOS, and is system set to boot in that mode by default. Most systems are now UEFI. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair